# pandas concat gives no entries after pandas rename

Tags: python, pandas

concatting dataframes worked well until I renamed columns of a specific dataframe. The renaming is before the concatting. The code for the renaming is as following and this dataframe will be returned after that.

```
ret=output_excel.rename(index=str, columns={"Home":str(self.hhid)+" Home","HH1 distance [km]":str(self.hhid)+" Distance Car1 [km]", "Energy [kWh]":str(self.hhid)+" Energy Car1 [kWh]"})
return ret
```

After I concat the different dataframes, the entries of the renamed columns are empty. How can this happen? If I do not rename the columns everything works fine.

## The concatting code:

```
for i in range(len(df_input)):
  O.read_input()
  O.compute_model()

#The dataframes are generated here
  O.output()
  df_old=O.output()
  df_old=df_old
  df_new=df_old
  df=pd.concat([df,df_new],axis=1)
```

Did I miss something? Is it easy to fix that?
Thanks for Help

Comment: It's not understandable what you want to achieve without the data your operating with. Please post `df_old.head()` and `df_new.head()`.

Comment: index=str might be causing the problem. str is a predefined function, you are using str in multiple contexts in the same line.

Comment: @sathyz I deleted index =str and it should work know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Deleting index=str inside .rename worked for me.

```
ret=output_excel.rename(columns={"Home":str(self.hhid)+" Home","HH1 distance [km]":str(self.hhid)+" Distance Car1 [km]", "Energy [kWh]":str(self.hhid)+" Energy Car1 [kWh]"})
return ret
```